# How to create multiple columns based on string.contains

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string, multiple-columns

I’m trying to create a new column/columns based on values within a single column using the following statement:

```
df.loc[df['Figure'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*BLUE)(?=.*HOTEL)'),'Location'] = 'BLUE HOTEL'
df.loc[df['Figure'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*Expensive)'),'Location'] = 'left'
df.loc[df['Figure'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*Cheap)'),'Location'] = 'Right'
```

If the original column contains more than 1 of the above string,   I’d want it to be inserted in a separate second new column and possibly a third new column.

So the goal would be to place the determined key words into different columns each.
Does anybody have any suggestions on how to write this code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about making 3 separate columns for each of the 3 cases ?

Answer (score 0):

By putting all possible matches into one single column and then expand columns when there are more than one match, it is prone to creating inconsistent columns difficult to operate afterwards.  It would be a better choice to create 3 separate columns for each of the 3 cases.  Let's explain by example:

**Create sample data:**

```
data = {'Figure': ['GREAT BLUE HOTEL', 'Expensive choice', 'Cheap and good', 'Nothing interesting', 'Cheap BLUE OCEAN HOTEL']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

    Figure
0   GREAT BLUE HOTEL
1   Expensive choice
2   Cheap and good
3   Nothing interesting
4   Cheap BLUE OCEAN HOTEL
```

**Run the codes:**

```
df['BLUE HOTEL'] = df['Figure'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*BLUE)(?=.*HOTEL)')
df['left'] = df['Figure'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*Expensive)')
df['right'] = df['Figure'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*Cheap)')
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
                   Figure  BLUE HOTEL   left  right
0        GREAT BLUE HOTEL        True  False  False
1        Expensive choice       False   True  False
2          Cheap and good       False  False   True
3     Nothing interesting       False  False  False
4  Cheap BLUE OCEAN HOTEL        True  False   True
```

Then, you can operate or filter the data by:

```
df[df['BLUE HOTEL']]        # filter entries with 'BLUE' and 'HOTEL'

Output:
                   Figure  BLUE HOTEL   left  right
0        GREAT BLUE HOTEL        True  False  False
4  Cheap BLUE OCEAN HOTEL        True  False   True


df[df['right']]             # filter entries with 'Cheap'

Output:    
                   Figure  BLUE HOTEL   left  right
2          Cheap and good       False  False   True
4  Cheap BLUE OCEAN HOTEL        True  False   True
```

Comment: Thank you, Maybe my example was incomplete. Instead of 3 columns there are around 20 key words which can be inserted into the 3 columns . Because one string can contain a maximum of 3 possible key words, there is a maximum of 3 columns(factor 1, factor 2, factor3). (These columns should be filled with the 20 or so occurring keywords.)The order by which they are inserted in the columns does not matter. For example; If one columns is filled with a keyword and the original string contains another keyword,  that second keyword will be placed in the second column..

Comment: @Wolfy14  In this case, the **mechanism** of implementing the logics should still be the same.  Replace `BLUE HOTEL`, `left`, `right` with the `factor1`, `factor2`, `factor3` and set the regex to extract the 20 key words accordingly.  So, any further question ?   As you do not provide all the data, the help here can at best suggest you a mechanism rather than the actual codes.

Comment: Alright thanks a lot for the insight. I think I'll give both methods a go and see what better suits the larger data system. Just how would you mean difficulty regarding inconsistency when expanding afterwards? I know this would leave column 2 and 3 with lots of empty values.

Comment: @Wolfy14 Column 1 will be mixed up with all kinds of matches, rather than only a single kind.  Then it is not as easy as you can manipulate if every column is just clearly defined to hold one kind of matches.